# ¿Cómo convertir un string multilínea en un array de líneas?

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando en Windows con Xampp y PHP7.

Quiero hacer algo como lo que se consigue con la función **`file()`** al leer un fichero de texto, es decir obtener un array donde cada elemento es una línea del texto, pero quiero hacerlo con un string multilínea, **¿hay alguna función nativa para hacerlo?**

Por el momento me funciona lo siguiente:

```
$str = "Esta es una 
    buena vaca pero
    no tanto como mi
    vieja vaca.";

$arr = explode( PHP_EOL , $str );
$res = array();
foreach($arr as $row) {
    $res[] = trim($row);
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump( $res );
```

cuya salida sería:

```
<pre>array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "Esta es una"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "buena vaca pero"
  [2]=>
  string(16) "no tanto como mi"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "vieja vaca."
}
```

> Editado:

Clase con soluciones hasta el momento:

```
final class StrTools
{
    /**
     * Cuts a multi-row string into rows
     *
     * @param  string       $str
     * @return array
     */
    public static function cutRows(string $str)
    {

        $arr = explode(PHP_EOL , $str);
        $res = array();
        foreach($arr as $row) {
            $res[] = trim($row);
        }

        return $res;
    }

    /**
     * Cuts a multi-row string into rows
     *
     * @param  string       $str
     * @return array
     */
    public static function cutRows2(string $str)
    {

        $arr = explode(PHP_EOL , $str);
        array_walk($arr, ['self', 'trimRows']);

        return $arr;
    }

    /**
     * Cuts a multi-row string into rows
     * From https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/128451 (user: Huskie)
     *
     * @param  string       $str
     * @return array
     */
    public static function cutRows3(string $str)
    {
        return preg_split('/\r/', $str);
    }

    /**
     * Cuts a multi-row string into rows
     * From https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/128451 (user: Huskie)
     * (updated regex)
     *
     * @param  string       $str
     * @return array
     */
    public static function cutRows4(string $str)
    {
        return preg_split('/\n|\r\n?/', $str);
    }
    public static function cutRows4xxx(string $str)
    {
        $arr = preg_split('/\n|\r\n?/', $str);
        array_walk($arr, ['self', 'trimRows']);

        return $arr;
    }

    /**
     * Cuts a multi-row string into rows
     * From https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/128451 (user: Marcos)
     *
     * @param  string       $str
     * @return array
     */
    public static function cutRows5(string $str)
    {
        return array_map('trim', preg_split('/\R/', $str));
    }


    /**
     * Cleans whitespaces in begin and end of a string
     *
     * @param  string       $str
     * @param  mixed
     */
    private static function trimRows(string &$value, $key)
    {
        $value = trim($value);
    }

} //class
```

Tests

```
$str = "Esta es una
    buena vaca pero
    no tanto como mi
    vieja vaca.";

echo '<pre>';
var_dump(StrTools::cutRows($str));
echo '<br>';
var_dump(StrTools::cutRows2($str));
echo '<br>';
var_dump(StrTools::cutRows3($str));
echo '<br>';
var_dump(StrTools::cutRows4($str));
echo '<br>';
var_dump(StrTools::cutRows4xxx($str));
echo '<br>';
var_dump(StrTools::cutRows5($str));
echo '<br>';
```

Salidas test:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(68) "Esta es una
    buena vaca pero
    no tanto como mi
    vieja vaca."
}

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(68) "Esta es una
    buena vaca pero
    no tanto como mi
    vieja vaca."
}

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(68) "Esta es una
    buena vaca pero
    no tanto como mi
    vieja vaca."
}

array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "Esta es una"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "    buena vaca pero"
  [2]=>
  string(20) "    no tanto como mi"
  [3]=>
  string(15) "    vieja vaca."
}

array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "Esta es una"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "buena vaca pero"
  [2]=>
  string(16) "no tanto como mi"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "vieja vaca."
}

array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "Esta es una"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "buena vaca pero"
  [2]=>
  string(16) "no tanto como mi"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "vieja vaca."
}
```

Comment: por qué no te es funcional como la tienes? quizás con tu respuesta a mi pregunta yo podría codificar una solución que se adapte a tus propósitos. Porque como está actualmente descrito no es ningún problema, no hay nada que "arreglar" o solucionar como tal.

Comment: Quiero saber si hay una función nativa para hacerlo o una mejora de mi método.

Answer (score 5):

En complemento a la respuesta de [@Huskie](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/128458/16597)

- Un salto de linea esta definido diferente según los distintos Sistemas Operativos; `\r\n`, `\r` o `\n`.

  Usando expresiones regulares para separar la cadena y capturar cualquiera de los 3 casos, se puede usar [`\R`](http://php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.escape.php)
- Para remover los caracteres de "*espacio en blanco*" de los valores en un arreglo podemos usar [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php) junto con [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.trim.php)

### Solución:

```
$claves = array_map('trim', preg_split('/\R/', $str));
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/HFPN95115)</kbd>

Comment: Mis disculpas ya ví la demo. Por algún motivo no me cargaba el demo, lo que no ví fue el trim que colocaste pero al cargar el demo si me di cuenta. Esta perfecta porque evita que separe por espacios en blanco. Yo la tildé correcta

Comment: @Huskie, creo que así esta bien, tu respuesta es muy buena, la mía complementa.

Comment: Si @Marcos esta genial la acotación! Muchas gracias, estaba intentando adaptarla con R pero no me pasó por la mente usar el trim y entonces tuve que editar mi respuesta con una expresión regular que generé para que tomara los 3 casos sin el espacio en blanco.

Comment: Mi +1 (luego borro este comentario :)

Comment: Me parece la mejor solución por el momento. Añado un método incorporando la misma a mi código de pruebas.

Answer (score 4):

> ¿Cómo convertir un string multilínea en un array de líneas?

Lo puedes lograr de la siguiente manera:

```
$str = "Esta es una 
    buena vaca pero
    no tanto como mi
    vieja vaca.";

$claves[] = preg_split('/\n|\r\n?/', $str); // función nativa php preg_split más
                                      //expresión regular que indica 
                                      //salto de línea tanto para unix como
                                      //linux y windows

var_dump($claves);
```

La salida será un único arreglo en el que cada elemento representa una línea del string multilínea que utilizamos de entrada:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(12) "Esta es una " [1]=> string(28) " buena vaca pero" [2]=> string(29) " no tanto como mi" [3]=> string(24) " vieja vaca." } }
```

Puedes ver la imágen con el resultado [image: aquí]

También puedes copiar y pegar mi solución en [php tester online](http://phptester.net) que es una herramienta que te permite ejecutar php sin instalar nada en tu pc.

**Edit:** Gracias al comentario de @AlvaroMontoro se pudo estandarizar la expresión regular a multiplataforma (para que la expresión regular también sea valida danto en unix como en linux). Modifiqué la expresión regular a `/\n|\r\n?/` con el fin de que el código se pueda utilizar para validar los saltos de línea de linux, unix y windows.

Para que observes que ahora también funciona en linux te dejo la imágen de mi prueba en maquina virtual con linux corriendo [image: aquí]. Te debo la captura de pantalla de unix ya que no poseo este sistema, agradecería si algún usuario modifica mi respuesta y coloca la captura de imagen del código funcionando en unix.

Eso es todo. Un Saludo.

Comment: De primeras me parece mejor que mi solución actual, te doy un voto positivo. Saludos.

Comment: ¿No debería ser `‘/\n/’`? `\r` es el retorno de carro y `\n` es el salto de línea. Podría fallar en UNIX/Linux donde la separación entre líneas es sólo `\n` (en Windows es `\r\n`)

Comment: @Huskie Después de leer tu respuesta, lo probé en un Mac (sistema basado en Unix) y con `'/\r/'` no funciona, pero sí con `'/\n/'`, por eso escribí mi comentario. Pero, por favor, pruébalo y compruébalo por ti mismo.

Comment: Listo! @AlvaroMontoro ya he probado en Linux y también funciona. Gracias por la observación ya he editado la respuesta y colocado una imagen que muestra que también funciona en linux por lo que ya funciona en unix, linux y windows. Confié en que la página phptester estaba corriendo en alguna distro linux (por cuestiones de seguridad obvias) pero con tu observación me di cuenta que no es así. Gracias nuevamente

Comment: Tu código funciona cortando por `\n` porque las `\r` sobrantes son eliminadas por la función `trim`, pero no funcionará con un archivo creado en un Mac, cuyo separador de línea es un `\r`.

Comment: @OscarGarcia ya desarrollé la expresión regular que toma tanto \n como \r y la unión de ambas. Así mi código es aplicable a las 3 plataformas. Te recomiendo lo pruebes...

Comment: A partir de Mac OS X se usa `\n` como separador de línea como en Linux, en mi respuesta tienes una definición de cadena de prueba.

Comment: He actualizado el código de mi pregunta, incluí la actualización de tu "regex" en los métodos "cutRows4" y "cutRows4xxx", fijate que el primero esta tal y como tu lo usas y si te fijas bien en las salidas que obtienes tienes strings con un montón de espacios al principio, por eso hice el segundo método.

Answer (score 2):

Complemento a [la respuesta de Marcos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/128560/127), que ya complementaba a [la respuesta de Huskie](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/128458/127).

Viendo que los espacios horizontales están alrededor del salto de línea, podemos evitar usar `trim()` si los sacamos en el split con [`\h`](http://php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.escape.php).

```
$claves = preg_split( '/\h*+\R\h*/', $str);
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/qSktR4

> Nota: Si hubiese espacios a eliminar al inicio de la primera línea o al final de la última, ahí se debería usar
>
> ```
> $claves = preg_split( '/\h*+\R\h*/', trim($str));
> ```
>
> De todas formas, sigue evitado tener que aplicarlo en cada línea individualmente.

Comment: Hola. Me parece que afinas la solución, aunque si no controlas el contenido del string, se puede dar la situación que ya comentas. Sería entonces necesario seguir usando **trim()**, o no, de acuerdo a la situación. Tienes mi voto, un saludo.

Comment: @Orici depende de cada caso y lo que se quiera obtener, que no está especificado en la pregunta. Si se quieren eliminar espacios al inicio de la primera línea y al final de la última, basta con pasar `trim($str)` como parámetro a `preg_split()`, evitando tener que aplicarlo en cada línea individualmente

Comment: tienes razón. Ahora mismo, no recuerdo en que situación se me planteó la pregunta, no se si partía de una entrada de formulario, parte de un fichero, o alguna otra cosa, pero creo que el texto en principio no era algo que pusiera yo.